# Подключение Яндекс.Карты и оверлей

Tags: html, css, javascript

К странице в блоке head подключается Яндекс-карта

```
<!-- Карта -->
    <script src="http://api-maps.yandex.ru/2.0/?load=package.full&mode=debug&lang=ru-RU" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    // Как только будет загружен API и готов DOM, выполняем инициализацию
        ymaps.ready(initMap);
        function initMap() {
            // Создание экземпляра карты и его привязка к контейнеру с
            // заданным id ("map")
            ymaps.geocode("Россия, Калуга, улица Глаголева, 52", {results: 1}).then(function (res) {
                geoObj = res.geoObjects.get(0);
                var myMap = new ymaps.Map('yandexMap', {
                    center: geoObj.geometry.getCoordinates(),
                    zoom: 16
                }), 
                geoObject1 = new ymaps.Placemark(myMap.getCenter(), {
                    balloonContentHeader: 'Калуга, улица Глаголева, д. 52',
                },{
                    iconImageHref: '/img/placemark.png',
                    iconImageSize: [73,76],
                    iconImageOffset: [-45,-65]
                });
                myMap.controls
                    .add('zoomControl')
                    .add('typeSelector')
                    .add('mapTools');
                myMap.geoObjects.add(geoObject1);
            });
        }
    </script>
```

и на странице есть всплывающее окно, которое отображается одновременно с затемнением фона (за затемнение фона отвечает блок c `id="semitransparentoverlay"` )

```
<div id="semitransparentoverlay"></div>
<!-- Заказать обратный звонок -->

<div id="order-callback" class="modalmsg">

</div>
```

CSS

```
#semitransparentoverlay {
display: none;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
position: fixed;
top: 0;
left: 0;
background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
z-index: 1000;
}

.modalmsg {
    width: 726px;
    height: auto;
    padding: 55px 90px 30px 90px;
    position: fixed;
    background: #fff;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    z-index: 1005;
    margin-left: -363px;
    display: none;
}
```

Скрипт

```
$('.contact-us-link').click (function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
    $('#order-callback, #semitransparentoverlay').fadeIn('200');
});

$('.modalmsg .closebtn').click (function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
    $('.modalmsg, #semitransparentoverlay').fadeOut('200');
});
```

В Гугл Хроме на всех страницах затемнение фона и всплывающее окно работают нормально, а на той странице, где подключена карта, всплывающее окно отображается, а блок затемнения фона отображается только если перейти в Инструмент разработчика. Создается впечатление, что дело в карте, так как если её убрать из кода страницы, то все отображается нормально.
В Опере и ФФ такой баг не воспроизводится. 
Можно как это поправить в Хроме ?

Comment: а если с помощью z-index принудительно поставить оверлей фона выше дива карты? точнее, поскольку у модалки и оверлея з-индекс уже задан, то поставьте контейнеру карты я-индекс, скажем, 10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Не, изменение z-index не помогло, помогло добавить в скрипты такую функцию

```
jQuery.fn.redraw = function() {
    return this.hide(0, function() {
        $(this).show();
    });
};
```

и вызвать её для оверлея

```
$('.contact-us-link').click (function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
    $('#semitransparentoverlay').redraw();
    $('#order-callback, #semitransparentoverlay').fadeIn('200');    
});
```